# Why getting wrong application name shown under its icon in the home screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, localizable.strings

I have a strange situation when using different languages in my app.

Let say I have those InfoPlist.strings

- English
- English (Canada)
- English (United States)
- English (United Kingdom)
- French
- French (Canada)
- French (France)

In each InfoPlist I have a line similar to the one below when I identify each combinaison. For example, here, it is for English (Canada):

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "EN-CA";
```

In XCode, I configured the `English` as the default one. This will change the `developmentRegion` field in the project.

I install the application to the iPhone with iOS 17.2

Then, I start to change the iOS language and region from the `Settings->General->Language & Region`.

It is here the behavior becomes strange and where I need your help to understand.

Here what I see for the app name under the app icon when changing the phone language and regions:

(Language (Region): App name)

- English (Canada): EN        **<-- WHY not EN-CA?**
- French (Canada): FR-CA
- French (United States): FR
- English (United States): EN **<-- WHY not EN-US?**
- English (United Kingdom): EN-GB
- English (France): EN-GB     **<-- WHY not EN?**
- French (France): FR
- English (United Arab Emirates): EN

And now, adding to that, if I try to delete the application, the alert message will contain the right application name. For example, when trying to delete the first example, the application name will be "EN-CA"

Anybody can explain to me what is going on behind the scene?

Is it true it is a limitation from Apple: https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/742591

Is there any official documentation?

Thanks

Comment: Really nice test. I can certainly guess why this is but I don't know how to find out the official rules.